# How to display submenu in vertical flip when hover menu?

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to make vertical flip when hover menu (sub menu), but it took so long to figure it out , still can't find solution !!! I wanna make like this site menu flip http://www.elegantthemes.com/preview/Extra/

```css
/* entire container, keeps perspective */
.flip-container {
 perspective: 1000px;
}
 /* flip the pane when hovered */
 .sub:hover ~ .flipper{
  transform: rotateX(180deg);

 }

.flip-container, .front, .back {
 width: 320px;
 height: 480px;
}

/* flip speed goes here */
.flipper {
 padding: 5rem;
 background: red;
 transition: 0.6s;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
 transform-origin: 100% 213.5px;
 position: relative;
}

/* hide back of pane during swap */
.front, .back {
 backface-visibility: hidden;

 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
}

/* front pane, placed above back */
.front {
 z-index: 2;
 /* for firefox 31 */
 transform: rotateX(0deg);
}

/* back, initially hidden pane */
.back {
 transform: rotateX(-180deg);
}
* {
 margin:0;
 padding: 0;
 font-size: .95rem;
}
nav {
 display: inline-flex;
 list-style-type: none;
 width: 100%;
 background: #ccc;
}
nav li {
 color:#494949;
 padding: 1rem;
 width: 30%;
 text-align: center;
 cursor: pointer;
}
nav li:hover {
 background: #fff;
}
@media (min-width: 800px) {
 nav li {
  width: 6rem;
 }
}
```

```html
<nav>
 <li class="sub">Submenu ^</li>
 <li>About</li>
 <li>Contact</li>
</nav>
<div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
 <div class="flipper">
  <div class="front">
   front content
  </div>
  <div class="back">
   back content -->
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to flip the submenu, when hovered over the menu? Such that the front contnent makes a 3d transformed flip, thus showing the back content?

Comment: ok @spirit , show me example code !!

Comment: Problem is, your code isn't clear to me. Do you need the back content to stay the way it is? But flip the fron content on hover over submenu?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for? I think the secret is you only want to rotate it 90 degrees initially, so you don't have to worry about backface viz or any of that stuff.
https://jsfiddle.net/97b865hc/6/

HTML and CSS:

```css
#menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
}

#submenu {
  background-color: red;
  transform: rotateX(90deg);
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}

#menu:hover #submenu {
  animation-duration: 3;
  transform: none;
  transition: all 2s;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  Main Menu
  <div id="submenu">
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
      <li>Item 4</li>
      <li>Item 5</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```